# How to compare date in javascript in this format?

Tags: javascript, date

How to compare today's date time with `2016-06-01T00:00:00Z` format in javascript ?

I get `2016-06-01T00:00:00Z` date format from backend. I want to check this with todays date, but not sure of how to check in that format.

I am extremely new to javascript.

Comment: Use `var d = new Date("2016-06-01T00:00:00Z")` ?

Comment: i cannot hard code values.

Comment: This is a string. You fetch a string from the backend. You just have to replace the string in my example.

Comment: Replace what @Seblor put inside the parenthesis with whichever variable containing the date that you get from server side

Answer (score 2):

If you search a little you can found the solution.

You have to parse your string into Js Date and compare it with today's date.

```js
var stringDate ="2016-06-01T00:00:00Z";

var jsDate = new Date(stringDate).getTime(); //getTime() => time in ms
var today = new Date().getTime();

console.log("date is oldest than today :", jsDate < today)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my comment on the question, you can quickly do it in one line. @Alexis answer is a bit overkill (no offense)

```
var result = new Date("2016-06-01T00:00:00Z") > new Date ? "After now" : "Before now";
```

Comment: this doesn't work. you can't compare Date object like this, and there's a typo error ;)

Comment: Nope. it works fine. doing math comparaison will use the timestamp, so integers.

Comment: Really ? Try it, it told me that 2016-06-01 is after now. It can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Oh my bad, I mixed up the results. it's the other way around, gonna edit

Comment: you always have the second result cause you can't compare date object like this ! Your solution is wrong.

Comment: 1) I removed the substraction. 2) you can. Dates are just timestamp integers with some functions on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149024/discussion-between-seblor-and-alexis).

Comment: Take a look at the link in my comment ! Date are object and not timestamp ! you have to call the getTime() method to get the timestamp !

Answer (score 0):

use the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and `Date#getTime` which returns the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. Pretty simple.

```js
let 
  dateStr        = "2016-06-01T00:00:00Z"
  d1             = new Date(dateStr),
  d2             = new Date(),
  d1IsBeforeD2   = d2.getTime() > d1.getTime()
;

console.log(d1IsBeforeD2);
```